# How to custom code folding for Scala in intelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have seen this blog: [Custom code folding regions in IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/)

But it's useful for **Java**, it doesn't work on **Scala**.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed for scala. I didn't have to adjust anything and was able to use region/endregion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make that work what I do is add a new line after

```
  //<editor-fold desc="Description">
```

and before too

```
  //</editor-fold>
```

so it code will look like

```
  //<editor-fold desc="Description">

  def save() = {
    //save
  }

  def findOne() = {
    //fineOne
  }

  //</editor-fold>
```

If code folding is still not available you can delete **`>`** from   `//<editor-fold desc="Description">` and add it again and it will work.

I think its a bug and that's the workaround that I'm doing.

Comment: Cheers !! Glad I was able to help

Comment: this seems to have been broken again on IJ 2017

Comment: @DexterLegaspi folding indicator is broken, but (semi-broken) functionality is still as answer describes

Comment: "If code folding is still not available you can delete > ... and add it again and it will work" <<<<< THIS!!! What an annoying bug! Thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: Bug in [their bug-tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163883). Please voit for raise the top.

Comment: Doesn't work in IntelliJ 2020.1. When you collapse you dont see the description.

Comment: "if code folding is still not available you can delete > from //<editor-fold desc="Description"> and add it again and it will work."

*narrator from 2021*: it didn't.